# Twitter @Anywhere sessions expire after 2 hours

Tags: session, twitter, duration, twitter-anywhere

After adding Twitter @Anywhere to a site,  a user can log in just fine, but after 2 hours, their sessions have expired.   Can't seem to find anything on the wire that references twitter anywhere session durations.

Comment: It looks like Twitter is dropping a twitter_anywhere_identity cookie with an expiration set to end of session..  Guess I need to figure out where that's getting set and how to override it.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to override the cookie expiration via the API as [this](http://groups.google.com/group/twitter-dev-anywhere/browse_thread/thread/6dec430527fd2df8#) post to the Twitter Anywhere Development Google Group details.

In the thread, Matt Harris, one of Twitter's developer advocates summarizes:

> @anywhere doesn't share the
> twitter.com login but instead is a
> user  authorised connection - much
> like OAuth apps.  But, unlike OAuth
> apps, @anywhere is purely web-based so
> doesn't provide  access beyond the
> current session.
>
> If you want to
> provide a logged in system you would
> need to use your own  session
> management code. To use Twitter as the
> identity provider you might  want to
> consider "[Sign in with Twitter](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/sign_in_with_twitter)"
> instead though.